# Router instance differing in BackboneJS

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, backbone-routing

What is the difference between use as `this.initialize();` within router.js in BackboneJS  and

```
require(['router'],function(Router) {
    router      = Router;
    router.intialize();                         
});
```

How to get same instances?

Can any one help me, Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I want to implement code coverage Unit Testing (Jasmine.js 1.3.1).

For this, I need to pass router (exactly same instance what I have when running application without code coverage tool) instance to my Jasmine spec's .js file.

If it is not possible, to get same instance during specs execution, Kindly advise me How to get the instance using different approach.

If you need any clarification in this transition, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand this question. You can check the instance of a router object by doing `someobj instanceof Backbone.Router` - I suspect that what you pass here to the current module an instance of a Backbone router. But I don't see why you call the initialize method explicitly on the router instance as this constructor gets called implicitly on instantiation.

Comment: I need to write test cases in Jasmine for that I have to explicitly make call for router.intialize();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the `constructor`.  Backbone classes all have a method which gets run when you instantiate the class.  That `constructor` method is how your `initialize` method gets called when you do `new Backbone.Router()`.

As you can see in, the `constructor` for `Router`:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router = function(options) {
    options || (options = {});
    if (options.routes) this.routes = options.routes;
    this._bindRoutes();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

the main difference between calling `initialize` and instantiating a router is that when you instantiate it the routes are bound.

Well, that's the main Backbone difference.  There's also the Javascript difference between calling `new A.B()` and `A.B()`, which is that the `new` keyword creates a new object and sets it as the `this` inside your `constructor`/`initialize` function, whereas calling it directly the way you're doing sets `this` to the `Router` class itself.

Because you almost certainly don't want to be using your `Router` class as the `this` when you test your methods, what you likely want to do is just instantiate a `Rotuer` properly in your setup code.